# Servo motor (HSR-1425R) not running continuously

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, continuous-servo

I'm trying to programme a servo motor to reach certain positions. I have a 360 degrees servo motor, so I can not use the Servo library and I can only control the speed. Therefore I want to regulate the time for the pulse. The setup is simple, 5 V, GND and pin 9 from the Arduino to the motor.

```
int servo1 = 9;

void setup{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(servo1, OUTPUT);
}
void loop{
    digitalWrite(servo1, HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    Serial.println(digitalRead(servo1));
    digitalWrite(servo1, LOW);
    delay(5000);
    Serial.println(digitalRead(servo1));
}
```

Expected:
I expect the code to run the servo motor at full speed for 5 seconds.

Actual:
The motor runs at the first impulse and pauses for 10 seconds.

How can I improve the code to do what I expect?

Comment: what are your hardware connections and why are you reading an output pin?

Comment: My hardware connections are the three wires from the servo directly to the Arduino. I wanted to see what signals were sent.

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use the Servo library?  With continuous rotation servos it generally works where 0 spins one way 180 spins the other and something close to 90 stops it.

Comment: Also, to control that servo you don't just set the pin HIGH.  You have to send a specific pulse length that tells the servo how fast and what direction to rotate.  It is the same sort of signal that tells a regular servo what angle to go to.  That's why the Servo library is normally used to control these.

Answer (score 1):

Apply some impulse which you need your servo to work on

Answer (score 0):

Look at how servo motors are typically controlled. As far as I know there are no servos that can just be "enabled to rotate" like you seem to expect.
Usually a servo's position is set by applying a pulse of a specific length. This means you can apply a PWM signal with proper frequency. Then the duty cycle should be proportional to the servos position. From my experience timing is quite critical when controlling a servo, so going the way you do (timing a gpio's output state with `delay()`s) will not work well. You have to use the atmega's hardware modules (which already is the case when using the arduinos digital write) to achieve adequate timing.